# Opening LIDAR DEM in QGIS with several .adf files

Tags: dem, lidar

I have a LIDAR DEM dataset of a bay. What I got is a single folder with these files [image]

I found out that the w001001.adf is the one that contains all the raster data and that the dblbnd, hdr, prj.sta provides metadata, however, there are several other (z001001.adf, z001002.adf, z001003.adf, z001003x) files which are as heavy as the w001001.adf and I dont know what they are for? I'm pretty much a beginner with raster data.

Comment: This is an ArcInfo Grid dataset, with multiple tiles of data. Each of the "heavy" files contains the actual data.

Comment: More info about it here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-grid-format.htm